# What should I provide while applying for a working visa permit in Germany?

Tags: germany, working-visas

I will finish college this year, so I want to apply for the visa to travel immediately after finishing my final exams.

I can also provide a document that states that my expected graduation date will be in July, and also the company will provide me all other required documents. Do you have any advice for a specialist professional non-EU national on how to apply, so that I won't be rejected because I didn't provide the official certificate?

Comment: If you already have a job offer from a company in Germany, they should take care of most of the paperwork and advise you what you will need to submit. As a new graduate, are you really already a specialist professional?

Answer (score 1):

For some visa, the EU *defines* "highly skilled professional" as somebody who earns 1.5 times the average annual salary in that member state, with a signed work contract or a binding offer. That is called the [Blue Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Card_(European_Union)#Requirements). For Germany you would have to earn €52,000 per year, or €40.560 in certain technical jobs.

However, the Blue Card application is only made *after* the applicant arrives on a work visa (source: [BAMF](https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/EN/Publikationen/Flyer/flyer-blaue-karte.pdf?__blob=publicationFile)) or visa-free (citizens of Australia, Israel, Japan, Canada, South Korea, New Zealand, United States).

Comment: Ok then if i am highly skilled professional and also i will be eligible for the blue card after arriving at Germany and of course getting my working visa ... then can i apply for the visa starting from now instead of waiting till being graduate as it takes time ? 
and just providing another documents which shows that its my last semester and i will graduate soon .

Comment: The second link *says* that you apply after arrival. BTW, have you checked if your college qualifies as equivalent to an EU university degree?